# Creating XML from jupyter notebook and executing function

Tags: python, xml, jupyter-notebook

i am using jupyter notebook for writing my python program.

in that i defined a function, inside of which i defined a variable

that i can modify from outside.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

myVariable = 'abc'

def myfunc(id):
    ....
    ....
    a = myVariable
    ....
    ....


print df
```

can i create a xml file from it where the notebook runs and prints respective outputs

and  i want to be able to change my defined variable 'myVariable'.

i don't know if it's possible using jupyter notebooks, and i'm a beginner

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this link](http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html)

Jupyter notebook is basically a terminal of your regular python with magic commands added to it.

I suggest you to use a config file that the notebook will read every time to achieve the **i want to be able to change my defined variable 'myVariable'.** part.